# F# Button click event

Tags: button, f#, click

I am a beginner in F#, but have programmed a little in C # earlier.
I am trying to figure out how to write a ButtonClicEvent that will AppendText from a button (Or somewhere else) to a existing text in a textbox..

This is from C#:

```cs
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if the eventhandler contains more than one button
    var btn = (sender as Button);

    textBox.AppendText(btn.Text);
}
```

Need to know how to do that in F#.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I have started with something like this: Btn.Click.Add(fun evArgs ->

Comment: Have a look at this sample: http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2010/06/09/simple-mouse-move-event-in-f-with-winforms.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
btn.Click.Add(fun _ -> textBox.AppendText(btn.Text))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was too easy to ask :-) ..Earlier I got error messages Aboud the AppendText was not defined

Comment: @ISo, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it has helped you.

Answer (score 5):

There's a good site [F# Snippets](http://fssnip.net/)

A relevant example from that site:

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

// Create form, button and add button to form
let form = new Form(Text = "Hello world!")
let btn = new Button(Text = "Click here")
form.Controls.Add(btn)

// Register event handler for button click event
btn.Click.Add(fun _ ->
  // Generate random color and set it as background
  let rnd = new Random()
  let r, g, b = rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)
  form.BackColor <- Color.FromArgb(r, g, b) )

// Show the form (in F# Interactive)
form.Show()
// Run the application (in compiled application)
Application.Run(form)
```